# How to create a spectrogram image from an audio file in Python just like how FFMPEG does?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, speech-recognition, spectrogram

## My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import specgram
import librosa
import librosa.display
import numpy as np
import io
from PIL import Image

samples, sample_rate = librosa.load('thabo.wav')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[4, 4])
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.set_frame_on(False)
S = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=samples, sr=sample_rate)
librosa.display.specshow(librosa.power_to_db(S, ref=np.max))
buf = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(buf,  bbox_inches='tight',pad_inches=0)

# plt.close('all')
buf.seek(0)
im = Image.open(buf)
# im = Image.open(buf).convert('L')
im.show()
buf.close()
```

### Spectrogram produced

[image]

## Using FFMPEG

ffmpeg -i thabo.wav -lavfi showspectrumpic=s=224x224:mode=separate:legend=disabled spectrogram.png

### Spectrogram produced

[image]

Please help, i want a spectrogram that is exactly the same as the one produced by FFMPEG, for use with a speech recognition model exported from google's teachable machine.
[Offline recognition](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/speech-commands)

Comment: You are going to have to look through the ffmpeg documentation to see how it makes the specgram, the parameters it uses like the number of samples used for each dft and the number of samples of overlap of each dft there may be others.. Then figure out which parameters of `melspectrogram` or `pyplot.specgram` they correspond to. The `ffmpeg` looks *sharper* which probably means it is using more samples to produce each dft.

Comment: Why not just use ffmpeg?

Comment: @llogan i am trying to avoid using ffmpeg because i think it would create a lot of overhead in the realtime speech recognition app, it would mean capturing audio then writing it to a file for use with ffmpeg which then writes the ouptut image to a file again before it can be used.

Comment: [librosa.feature.melspectrogram](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.feature.melspectrogram.html) - play around with the `n_fft` and `hop_length` arguments. `n_fft` should always be a power of 2 (eg `pow(2,11)`). Increase `n_fft`, decrease  `hop_length` - some combination of the two should produce finer detail. `matplotlib.pyplot.specgram` has similar parameters. Decreasing `hop_length` will produce more *columns* in the spectrogram, increasing the size of the data. Increasing `n_fft` should produce finer frequency resolution (sharper peaks).

Comment: @hamandisheMk You can directly pipe the audio to ffmpeg which will avoid the intermediate file, and ffmpeg can output to pipe as well if you wanted to avoid image file output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly pipe the audio to `ffmpeg` which will avoid the intermediate file, and `ffmpeg` can output to pipe as well if you wanted to avoid image file output.

Demonstration using three instances of `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -f wav - | ffmpeg -i - -filter_complex "showspectrumpic=s=224x224:mode=separate:legend=disabled" -c:v png -f image2pipe - | ffmpeg -y -i - output.png
```

The first and last `ffmpeg` instances of course will be replaced with your particular processes for your workflow.